# Deciding if a given Language is Regular/Context-Free/Non Context-Free

Tags: context-free-grammar, regular-language, automata, formal-languages

I need some help with deciding if a given language is regular, context-free or not context-free. A brief, informal explanation is sufficient in the answer, hence no need to use pumping lemma.

Lets say I have the following lanugages:

```
L1 = { w ∈ {a, b, c, d}* | #a(w) is even, #b(w) = 1 mod 3, w does not have 
                           a substring abc }

L2 = { w  ∈ {a, b, c, d}* | #a(w) is even, #b(w) < #c(w) }

L3 = { w  ∈ {a, b, c, d}* | #a(w) < #b(w) < #c(w) }
```

This is my solution:

```
L1 = L2 ∩ L3 ∩ L4 where

L2 = #a(w) is even
L3 = #b(w) = 1 mod 3
L4 = w does not have a substring abc
```

A DFA can be constructed for L2, becuse L2 does not need infinite memory, so L2 is regular. For L3 the same reasoning as above. And for L4 we can construct a DFA that simply does not accept "abc", hence regular.

L1 is regular because regular languages are closed under ∩ .

For L2 we can divide the language into:

```
L2 = L3 ∩ L4 where

L3 = #a(w) is even
L4 = #b(w) < #c(w)
```

We know that a DFA can be constructed for L3, hence L3 is regular. L4 is context-free because we can construct a PDA where a stack is used to count the number of a:s and b:s.

L2 is hence context-free because the ∩ of a regular language and a context-free language result in a context-free language.

For L3 we can see that it's non context-free because we are limitied to 1 stack, and to do more than 1 comparison we need more stacks.

Is my reasonings rights ? I have a exam soon and need to know if I have got the idea behind this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct on all three counts. L1 is regular, L2 is context-free, and L3 is not context-free. You correctly apply closure properties for L1 and L2, and your reasoning is more or less correct for the last one. For the last one, I would caution you against using that rule... since there may be more than one way to think about how a language could be recognized, some of which require more than a stack, and some of which don't. Take, for instance, the non-context-free language L = {a^n b^n c^n}. The complement of this language is context-free, although sloppy application of the rule you use might lead you to believe otherwise (until you'd properly considered the matter).

Comment: Thank you soooo much :) I know that the reasoning on 3 is not so good. Is there any other argument that I can use for L3 ?

Comment: What about L4 = { w  ∈ {a, b, c, d}* | #a(w) < #b(w) < #c(w) <6 } ?
I suppose that it's context-free AND regular ? Becase a DFA with finite number of states could be constructed, a very big one, but still finite.

Comment: @mrjasmin To show that languages aren't context-free, the best bet is to use the pumping lemma for context-free languages. Unlike the pumping lemma for regular languages, the pumping lemma for context-free languages gives you a necessary *and* sufficient condition for a language to be context-free. It can be messy, but it will always work (and if it doesn't, then you're context-free). Sometimes, you can apply closure properties in the same way you did for regular languages, except that context-free languages are not closed under all the same operations.

Comment: @mrjasmin Yes, L4 is regular (hence also context-free) since you could construct a (very large) DFA for it. In fact, if you think about it, L4 must be a finite language, hence, it is definitely regular.